# Vue component not destroyed on dom change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue app that re-orders and filters a list of components.

```
<div id="my-app">
    <div v-for="item in listItems">
        <my-item v-bind:item="item"></my-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I re-order or filter the list, the component does not fire a destroyed event which I need to add a class to the container and remove the image src inside.

Comment: please share snippet or js fiddle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not set a [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key) on each item, then Vue will re-use the existing component instances, changing only the bound `item`.

You should set `key` to a value which uniquely identifies that particular item.

```vue
<my-item :item="item" :key="item.id">
```

Now when a particular item is removed from the list, the associated `<my-item>` component will be destroyed and not re-used.